# Jquery mobile left swipe menu with independent scrolling

Tags: jquery-mobile, panel, swipe

I have this example:

jsfiddle.net/6mNpp/

Is it possible, to prevent the scrolling of the left menu, when it is open and the whole site is scrolling? I mean, when I open the left menu and scroll the content, then the left menu is scrolling as well. How to make them with independent scrolling?

Thanks
Nik

Comment: http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/#panel-positioning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the panel fixed with CSS. With this, the left panel is not scrolling when the content is scrolling.

The code is the same that the JSFiddle, just add in the style, `position:fixed`

```html
<div data-role="panel" id="defaultpanel" data-display="push" data-theme="b" style="overflow:auto; position: fixed;" data-animate="false">
```

Reference: [Positioning Panels](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/#panel-positioning)

Comment: Thanks! And now how to make the left navigation UL with scroller, without to set any height? I mean if I have 30 links on the left side, I don't need to set height. But without hight there is no Y-scroller coming.

Comment: @Jabel Márquez After doing this, the left menu gets fixed to its position and it doesn't scroll at all. How to fix this without setting the height, because in mobile devices, the height of the screen changes on orientation change, but the height which is manually set doesn't change and hence the menu hides some of the elements in it. How do I fix this?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Using "overflow: scroll" is of no use because of the height set by the framework. Waiting for JQM 1.7 doesn't seem like an option right now.

Answer (score 0):

More info...

JqueryMobile roadmap http://jquerymobile.com/roadmap/ says independent scolling should arrive in version 1.7

Another possible hack workaround maybe adding the divs via an iframe may offer a clumsy solution.